# Using multiple values from object in one method, angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

Multiple values from a MQTT-CLient will be saved in one obejct(message). 
Now i want to consume all of the values seperate through one method and inject them in another component.
This is my Client-**Service**, where i am using the onMessage method. At the moment i am just passing on the object (message.geometry).

```
@Injectable()
export class GeomqttService {

  client: any;

  geohistory = [
    {
      topic: '',
      timestamp: '',
      payloadstring: '',
      geometry: ''
    }
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client('wpsdemo.gia.rwth-aachen.de', 8080, 's');
    this.onConnectionLost();
    this.client.connect({onSuccess: this.onConnected.bind(this)});
  }


  onMessageArrived = (message: Paho.MQTT.Message) => {
    this.geohistory.push({
      'topic': 'temp',
      'timestamp': message.timestamp,
      'payloadstring': message.payloadString,
      'geometry': message.geometry
    });

  };


onConnected() {
    console.log('Connected');
    this.client.geosubscribe('node/m1/temperature', '', 'BBOX(-180 -90, 180 90)', 'INTERSECTS');
    //this.sendMessage('HelloWorld');
    this.client.onMessageArrived = (message: Paho.MQTT.Message) => {
      this.onMessage(message.geometry);
      console.log('Message arrived: ' + message.geometry);
    }
  }

  public onMessage(message: string) {}
```

And in the **component** i want to use all the values from the object message. At the momment i am just using the value geometry.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {GeomqttService} from './geomqtt.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-paho',
  templateUrl: './paho.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./paho.component.css']
})
export class PahoComponent implements OnInit {


  data = [
    {
      topic: '',
      timestamp: '',
      payloadstring: '',
      geometry: ''
    }
  ];


  constructor(private geomqttService: GeomqttService) {
    this.geomqttService.onMessage = (message: string) => {
      this.data = [{topic: 'test', timestamp: '' , payloadstring: '', geometry: message}];
      console.log(this.data);
    };
  }

  ngOnInit(){}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier to create a `paho.ts` and then define fields you want (out of data form) for example:

```
export  class  Paho {

    private  topic:  string;
    private  timestamp: string;
    private payloadstring: string;
    private geometry: string;

    public getTopic(): string 
    { // create getter for other 3 attributes
        return this.topic;
    }

    public setTopic(t: string) 
    { // create setter for other 3 attributes
        this.topic= t;
    }

    public function1(topic: string): boolean {
        return true;
    }

    private function2(): string{
    }

}
```

you can create an new Paho every where you want and work with it easily by using getter/setter :)

Comment: The idea is to consume the values thorugh one method!

Comment: Could you precise  the getter/setter method in this case a little bit? So do i need 4 getter and 4 setter methods?

Comment: I use getter/setter bcoz i defined attributes `private`; you can define `public` and reach them like this:   `let p: paho; p.topic="topicOne";`